# How can I fix my gnome desktop / X server in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: upgrade, xorg, amd-graphics

I have been struggling with this since yesterday evening:
I upgraded from 12.04 to 13.10 in steps using

```
do-release-upgrade
```

Since the last upgrade I got the "Low graphics mode" screen with the options which I cannot select because the mouse is gone and selecting with keyboard did not seem to work on that screen either.
I got out of there by switching to TTY1.

Trying to fix the problem I have installed graphics drivers from AMD I had already downloaded previously. When this did not fix the problem I just did

```
apt-get install --reinstall fglrx
```

This did not help so I started messing with my desktop environments. I read somewhere to try reinstalling `gdm` but than I set that as default over `lightdm` which I was obviously using and then things got really fishy.

I never got the low graphics mode screen again but only terminal. after installing `gnome-session-fallback` I had a graphical loading screen again on boot but this crashes and shows terminal login.
I moved all my logs out of the default dir so I could see only the new ones. X.org shows some EE (error) that no compatible graphics card was found.

I have ATI Mobility Radeon 4570 in my laptop. As I said before I have tried installing the latest drivers.

Can anyone help me troubleshoot this problem further?

Answer (score 1):

I found some additional help [here on crunchbang forums](http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=8992)

It told me there was probably something wrong with my installation of `fglrx` so I uninstalled that through apt-get.

After a reboot after this uninstall I finally got my desktop back. But this time it is the Unity desktop while I had removed that in my previous release.

I reinstalled `gnome-session-fallback` and it seems my session is restored as I wanted it after choosing Gnome Session before logging in.